# How to attach a simple data.frame to a SpatialPolygonDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, merge, polygon, spatial, dataframe

I have (again) a problem with combining data frames in R. But this time, one is a SpatialPolygonDataFrame (`SPDF`)  and the other one is usual data.frame (`DF`). The `SPDF` has around 1000 rows the `DF` only 400. Both have a common column, QDGC

Now, I tried

```
oo <- merge(SPDF,DF, by="QDGC", all=T)
```

but this only results in a normal data.frame, not a spatial polygon data frame any more.
I read somewhere else, that this does not work, but I did not understand  what to do in such a case (has to do something with the ID columns, merge uses)

oooh such a hard question, I quess...

Thanks!
Jens

Comment: in Y2021 this is relevant [49032217](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032217/inner-joining-two-sf-objects-by-non-sf-column)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let df = data frame, sp = spatial polygon object and by = name or column number of common column. You can then merge the data frame into the sp object using the following line of code

```
sp@data = data.frame(sp@data, df[match(sp@data[,by], df[,by]),])
```

Here is how the code works. The match function inside aligns the columns so that order is preserved. So when we merge it with sp@data, order is correctly preserved. A quick check to see if the code has worked is to inspect the two columns corresponding to the common column and see if they are identical (the common columns get duplicated and it is easy to remove the copy, but i keep it as it is a good check)

Comment: Thank you veeery much! You saved my evening ! And probably also the whole week!  It worked perfectly well.

Comment: @Ramnath Will this solution work if spatial data frame has more rows (polygons) than the merged data? And also in opposite case - when there are more observations in joined data?

Comment: How would this be different if both objects are `SpatialP*DataFrame`s?

Comment: I think you could try replacing `df` with `df@data[,by]` if `df` were also a `SpatialP*DataFrame`

Answer (score 21):

It is as easy as this:

```
require(sp) # the trick is that this package must be loaded!

oo <- merge(SPDF,DF, by="QDGC")
```

I've tested by myself. But it only works if you use [merge from package sp](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/merge). This is the default when `sp` package is loaded. `merge` function is then overloaded and `sp::merge` is used if the first argument is spatial structure.

Comment: This worked really well for me!
However, I think it is worth pointing out that some problems might appear if the dataframe and the SPDF do not have the same number of rows. I kept getting an error ("number of objects mismatch") originated by this issue.
Finally, I was able to perform the merge by adding "all.x = TRUE" (where x is the SPDF).

Comment: this is fantastic i tested it in 2021. my df has more lines than my shp, but it worked. I recommend this answer.

Answer (score 7):

merge can produce a dataframe with more rows than the originals if there's not a simple 1-1 mapping of the two dataframes. In which case, it would have to copy all the geometry and create multiple polygons, which is probably not a good thing.

If you have a dataframe which is the same number of rows as a SpatialPointsDataFrame, then you can just directly replace the @data slot.

```
library(sp)
example(overlay) # to get the srdf object
srdf@data
spplot(srdf)
srdf@data=data.frame(x=runif(3),xx=rep(0,3))
spplot(srdf)
```

if you get the number of rows wrong:

```
srdf@data=data.frame(x=runif(2),xx=rep(0,2))
spplot(srdf)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

Comment: Okay I did the follwing:  (1) oo <- merge(SPDF,DF, by="QDGC", all=T)  (2)  SPDF@data <- oo  (3) plot(SPDF)  the data is now there but in very wrong order. perhaps I should sort something?

Comment: ouch. i should have checked that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the function `joinCountryData2Map` in the [rworldmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/) package can give inspiration. (But I may be wrong, as I was last time.)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is to use `append_data` function from the [`tmaptools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmaptools/index.html) package. It is called with these arguments:

```
append_data(shp, data, key.shp = NULL, key.data = NULL,
  ignore.duplicates = FALSE, ignore.na = FALSE,
  fixed.order = is.null(key.data) && is.null(key.shp))
```

It's a bit unfortunate that it's called append since I'd understand append more ina sense of `rbind` and we want to have something like `join` or `merge` here.

Ignoring that fact, function is really useful in making sure you got your joins correct and if some rows are present only on one side of join. From the docs:

> Under coverage (shape items that do not correspond to data records),
>   over coverage (data records that do not correspond to shape items
>   respectively) as well as the existence of duplicated key values are
>   automatically checked and reported via console messages. With
>   `under_coverage` and `over_coverage` the under and over coverage key
>   values from the last append_data call can be retrieved,

Answer (score 0):

If it is two shapefiles that are needed to be merged to a single object, just use `rbind()`.

When using `rbind()`, just make sure that both the arguments you use are `SpatialDataFrames`. You can check this using `class(sf)`. If it is not a dataframe, then use `st_as_sf()` to convert them to a `SpatialDataFrame` before you rbind them.

Note : You can also use this to append to `NULLs`, especially when you are using a result from a loop and you want to cumulate the results.