# Associating custom data to shapefiles in r

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal, r-maptools

This is probably an obvious question.

I have an Australia Shapefile (can be found here http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.001July%202011?OpenDocument)  and some custom data which contains latitudes and longitudes for a number of people.

How can I join the shape file to the custom data using latitude and longitude so that I can create a population distribution map and colour the segments of the map accordingly?

Thank you.

Comment: The spatialDataFrame class supports merging. Have you done any research on the facilities of the 'recommended' `sp`-package? There's an entire CRAN Task View on the general topic.

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered fully here. But look [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45327/tutorials-to-handle-spatial-data-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650636/how-to-attach-a-simple-data-frame-to-a-spatialpolygondataframe-in-r) for how to merge data frames with shapefiles. Also, as in the other comment, see the extensive documentation of R packages like `sp` and `spdep`. I can highly recommend the latter.