# R spplot labels in wrong places

Tags: r, plot, label, r-sp

I am working with the US census gazetteer data file (zcta5) which is publicly available.  The version I am using has files named tl_2015_us_zcta510.shp, dbf...  Plotting the file works fine.

The issue I am having seems to happen when I subset the SpatialDataPolygonsDataFrame with a larger number of polygons.  But when I use a small subset the labels work fine.

The labels I need identify assigned groupings of postal codes an individual 5-digit polygon area belongs to.  For example - for Ashtabula, OH postal codes I need all the postal codes to have a label in the middle of it that reads "503".  I have labels for all the other Ohio postal code groupings - called "PostalGroupNumber" and in table form the data all checks out to be correct.

So I load libraries and read the full spatial data frame into memory:

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)
library(foreign)

#Load in the entire census gazatteer data file
zcta5=readShapeSpatial("~/R/PostalCodes/USA/US Postal Codes/ZCTA5/tl_2015_us_zcta510.shp")
```

Next: create vector of Ashtabula, OH postal codes:

```
ashtab.zips <- c("44003","44004","44005","44010","44030","44032","44041","44047","44048","44068","44076","44082","44084","44085","44088","44093","44099")
```

Next - subset zcta5 Spatial Data Frame to include only these postal codes:

```
ashtab <- zcta5[which(zcta5@data$GEOID10 %in% ashtab.zips),]
```

Next - add labels to new ashtab spatial data frame and plot:

```
ashtab@data <- cbind(ashtab@data, "PostalGroupNumber"="503")
l1 = list("sp.text", coordinates(ashtab), as.character(ashtab@data$PostalGroupNumber),col="black", cex=0.7,font=2)
spplot(ashtab,zcol="GEOID10", sp.layout=list(l1)
       ,main=list(label="PostalGroupNumber 503 Postal Areas",cex=2,font=1)
)
```

Which works and gives the following and correct plot of the postal areas of northeast Ohio with correct labels in them:

[image]

Pretty good - BUT - the scale on the right looks like it retained a huge number of GEOID10 levels where I expected only the subset of the 17 in the ashtab.zips vector.  Side Question (extra credit ;-)- why are those levels still there?

Now on to the main problem. Ohio postal codes all start with a 43... or a 44... - I have a csv file for just the 5-digit codes that are in Ohio, each with their assigned PostalGroupNumber which I read into a data frame, clean up and use to subset the main data frame like I did above:

```
oh <- read.csv("~/R/PostalCodes/OhioPostalGroupings/OH-PGAs-PostalCodes Only.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = c("character", "character", "character"))
oh$ZIP_CODE <- trimws(oh$ZIP_CODE)
ohzcta5 <- zcta5[which(zcta5@data$GEOID10 %in% oh$ZIP_CODE),]
l1 = list("sp.text", coordinates(ohzcta5), as.character(ohzcta5@data$GEOID10),col="black", cex=0.7,font=2)

spplot(ohzcta5,zcol="GEOID10", sp.layout=list(l1)
       ,main=list(label="Ohio Postal Code - PostalGroupNumbers",cex=2,font=1)
)
```

This time - just plot with labels of the GEOID10 value to see if it plots correctly and it does - hard to read here but zooming in shows correct postal codes in each polygon (this is not a great image but shape of OH is right and labels are correct...):

[image]

Now I need to add the PostalGroupNumber labels to the spatial data frame, and make a factor to color all the groups of postal codes together as the same color per group. So Ashtabula should all be one color and all have "503" labels in them - but they do not:

```
ohzcta5@data <- merge(ohzcta5@data, oh, by.x="GEOID10", by.y="ZIP_CODE", all.x=TRUE)
ohzcta5@data <- cbind(ohzcta5@data, "TAcolor"=as.factor(ohzcta5@data$PostalGroupNumber))
l1 = list("sp.text", coordinates(ohzcta5), as.character(ohzcta5@data$PostalGroupNumber),col="black", cex=0.7,font=2)

spplot(ohzcta5,zcol="GEOID10", sp.layout=list(l1)
       ,main=list(label="Ohio Postal Code - PostalGroupNumber",cex=2,font=1)
)
```

Which now looks like this:

[image]

A closer look at Ashtabula (northeast corner) now looks like this - What happened to the labels?:

[image]

The labels are all wrong - and yet when examining the ohzcta5@data the PostalGroupNumber is on the correct GEOID10 records.

Help!!!!  Losing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to two issues:
1) the issue of too many levels retained inthe spatial frame appearing on the spplot scale is resolved by using the base package "droplevels" for each of the factors in the spatial data frame.

2) Don't use "merge" because it re-orders the data so it no longer aligns to the correct polygon.  Instead use "match" as shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652472/4017087 (Thanks Ramnath!)

Comment: Thanks for solving your own problem! Assigning @data slots directly is recommended in general unless you know what you do, for the reason you identified. Package `sp` has a `merge` method for spatial objects which you could try as well.