# Is it possible to create a bubble map in R based on simple dataframe information per continents?

Tags: r

I want to create a bubble map, using a simple data frame, extracted from a survey, and show it as info per continents. Most of the libraries I found use country-level info or x-y coordinates.

I already calculate the count to have the final number for each bubble, so I have this data:
user_location count

```
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Africa                    1
2 Asia                      3
3 Europe                   13
4 North America             8
5 South America           122
```

The only library I found with the possibility of showing Continent info is `rworldmap`

```
install.packages("rworldmap")
library(rworldmap)

sPDF <- getMap()
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='REGION')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE7tn.png)
(Using 'REGION' I have a model with 7 continents, more accurate to the data I have)

The next thing I did was to merge my data with sPDF which is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650636/how-to-attach-a-simple-data-frame-to-a-spatialpolygondataframe-in-r) and adapted to my needs:

`sPDF@data = data.frame(sPDF@data, df[match(sPDF@data["REGION"], df["user_location"])])`

But I'm getting this error, because sPDF@data["REGION"] has a NA value

> Can't subset columns with `match(sPDF@data["REGION"], df["user_location"])`.
> Subscript `match(sPDF@data["REGION"], df["user_location"])` can't contain missing values.
> It has a missing value at location 1.

**Question 1**: Is this approach correct? Is there an easy way to add personal data to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, like a function I could be missing?

**Question 2**: Once I solve this problem, I'm planning to use 'mapBubbles' function, from the same library, like this:
`mapBubbles(sPDF, nameZSize = "count", mapRegion = "REGION")`
Is this correct?

Sorry if I add 2 questions in 1, it's my first time with R and I've been stuck with this map for over a week.

Comment: Perhaps you've already seen this, but here's a useful resource for example graphing code, in this case bubble maps: https://r-graph-gallery.com/bubble-map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `rworldmap`package, but it relies on some packages that were deprecated last year so here's a more future-proof solution.

Note that various warnings will pop up when running this code. Within the context of your goal, you can safely ignore them. These warning are either telling you the code is treating sphere-based coordinates as if they are on a flat (planar) surface, or that you have NA values in your data (as with the Oceania and Antarctica continents).

This example is very basic, and if it doesn't suit, update your question and I'll update the answer.

```
library(dplyr) # For data wrangling/pipes e.g. %>%
library(sf) # For spatial data
library(rnaturalearth) # For map data
library(ggplot2) # For plotting

# Tell sf to treat world map data as a 'flat' surface instead of a sphere
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

# Import world map, dissolve/union polygons by continent, and add bubble lon/lat
# locations for plotting
continents <- ne_countries(returnclass='sf') %>%
  # Russia has incorrect continent value, so need to change it
  mutate(continent = ifelse(sovereignt == "Russia", "Asia", continent)) %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  summarise(geom = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  filter(!continent == "Seven seas (open ocean)") %>%
  mutate(centroid_lon = st_coordinates(st_centroid(.))[,1],
         centroid_lat = st_coordinates(st_centroid(.))[,2])

# Your count data
dat <- read.table(text = "Africa;1
Asia;3
Europe;13
North America;8
South America;122", header = FALSE, sep = ";")
colnames(dat) <- c("continent", "count")

# Join count data to continents
continents <- left_join(continents, dat, by = "continent")

# Plot
ggplot(data = continents) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(aes(x = centroid_lon, y = centroid_lat, size = count)) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 10)) +
  labs(size = "Count") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())

# It is a good habit to turn S2 back on after you are done
sf_use_s2(TRUE)
```

[image: result]